# postgreSQL size on disk

Tags: postgresql, size

1/ How can I get the size of a table on disk ?
I tried

```
select table_name, pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public' 
order by 2 desc
```

but it's very low compare to what my cloud provider told me so i think it's the data size and not the data size on disk (the request return 27MB, my cloud provider told me I'm using 307MB)

2/ Is it possible to groupby this value by client ? (client is a column present in each tables)
I can also run multiple requests for each tables if it's easier
Thanks for your help

Comment: You forgot the indexes and other structures. Check pg_database_size() for the size of a single database

Comment: SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('mydb')) give me the same result (27MB)

Comment: And you want to use `pg_total_relation_size` instead of `pg_relation_size`. See [Admin functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html) for distinction.

Comment: Do you have more then one database in cluster?

Comment: When your cloud provider tells you this single database has a size of 307MB and your PostgreSQL server tells you that this single database is just 27MB, your provider should explain the difference. They can tell you how they measured the size

Comment: my cloud provider told data size is 27MB (the value I found) but the size on disk is 307MB

Comment: I'm guessing the difference is the actual Postgres server files e.g. logs, WAL, binaries, etc. I ran `du -sh` on a small Postgres cluster and it came back as 382M.

Comment: Maybe your cloud provider includes the size of backups they took

Comment: Well, I think the best is too ask them! Thanks for your help all